# Magnifying Glass (zoom) Cursor over image

Tags: css, fancybox, mouse-cursor

I'm looking for a solution to change the cursor to a magnifying glass upon hovering over a Fancybox image.

Like on Pinterest, when you hover an image (using chrome).

So far I have this which doesn't have cross-browser support.

```
.picture img {
    cursor:url(/img/layout/backgrounds/moz-zoom.gif), -moz-zoom-in;
}
```

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577326/cross-browser-custom-cursor-style

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For that you need to use a cursor file `.cur` and not a <s>`.gif`</s> file, so it will be like

```
.picture img {
    cursor: url(/img/layout/backgrounds/zoom.cur), -moz-zoom-in;
}
```

---

The above is when you wish to use a custom cursor using `.cur` file. If you are ok with the default cursor provided by the browsers, you could simply use the below.

```
cursor: zoom-in;
```

Comment: To clarify @Mr.Alien's answer: there does not seem to be a cross-browser built-in "magnifying glass cursor", as seen on http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/ `-webkit-zoom-in` is webkit only

Comment: To clarify even more: @Mr.Alien uses an absolute path because IE does not support relative path for cursor images.

Comment: Can we modify the size of the cursor from CSS as well?

Comment: @MayankSingh yes, you could use `cursor: zoom-in;`

Answer (score 50):

You can use:

```
.picture img{
    cursor: -moz-zoom-in; 
    cursor: -webkit-zoom-in; 
    cursor: zoom-in;
}
```

Comment: This works in newer FF...
I like this
cursor: -moz-zoom-in;
cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
cursor: zoom-in;

Answer (score 12):

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-cursors-newer), the relevant browsers now all support `cursor: zoom-in;`except IE of course. IE usage is down to 6.1% on w3schools... clock's a'ticking IE!

```
.picture img{
   cursor: zoom-in;
}
```

Comment: IE is gone! Woot!!!

Comment: [Internet Explorer gravestone in South Korea](https://www.reuters.com/lifestyle/oddly-enough/internet-explorer-gravestone-goes-viral-south-korea-2022-06-17/)

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out a way to make the cursor work on the image but it never worked as a cursor

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

.img-magnifier-container {
  position:relative;
}

.img-magnifier-glass {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: none;
  /*Set the size of the magnifier glass:*/
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
</style>
<script>
function magnify(imgID, zoom) {
  var img, glass, w, h, bw;
  img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  /*create magnifier glass:*/
  glass = document.createElement("DIV");
  glass.setAttribute("class", "img-magnifier-glass");
  /*insert magnifier glass:*/
  img.parentElement.insertBefore(glass, img);
  /*set background properties for the magnifier glass:*/
  glass.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
  glass.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
  glass.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * zoom) + "px " + (img.height * zoom) + "px";
  bw = 3;
  w = glass.offsetWidth / 2;
  h = glass.offsetHeight / 2;
  /*execute a function when someone moves the magnifier glass over the image:*/
  glass.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
  img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
  /*and also for touch screens:*/
  glass.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
  img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
  function moveMagnifier(e) {
    var pos, x, y;
    /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
    pos = getCursorPos(e);
    x = pos.x;
    y = pos.y;
    /*prevent the magnifier glass from being positioned outside the image:*/
    if (x > img.width - (w / zoom)) {x = img.width - (w / zoom);}
    if (x < w / zoom) {x = w / zoom;}
    if (y > img.height - (h / zoom)) {y = img.height - (h / zoom);}
    if (y < h / zoom) {y = h / zoom;}
    /*set the position of the magnifier glass:*/
    glass.style.left = (x - w) + "px";
    glass.style.top = (y - h) + "px";
    /*display what the magnifier glass "sees":*/
    glass.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + ((x * zoom) - w + bw) + "px -" + ((y * zoom) - h + bw) + "px";
  }
  function getCursorPos(e) {
    var a, x = 0, y = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
    a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
    /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
    x = e.pageX - a.left;
    y = e.pageY - a.top;
    /*consider any page scrolling:*/
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    return {x : x, y : y};
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Mouse over the image:</p>

<div class="img-magnifier-container">
  <img id="myimage" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/C07Jx1HcnAiXyAZNsp0E7wXHGiA9E9Tr5oEPQT3VkU3WSCOIOOBBEL3Sk8sEk-MjFJx0fw=s163" width="600" height="400">
</div>
<script>
/* Initiate Magnify Function
with the id of the image, and the strength of the magnifier glass:*/
magnify("myimage", 3);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```