# JavaScript how to change mouse cursor to an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, mouse

I've seen examples where you can change it to preset images that your operating system has; example:

```
$('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
```

But how about my own /img/my_image.png?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: is [this][1]

what you're looking for?
If so this should be marked as a duplicate

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336925/custom-cursor-image-css

Comment: Probably. I see the code "a.heroshot img {
cursor:url(/img/layout/backgrounds/moz-zoom.gif), -moz-zoom-in;
}", but I'm not sure how to implement it. What I have now is a button, and when clicked, I have a function handling that. Within that function I want to change the cursor to an image, but I'm not sure how to use this code.

Answer (score 26):

You can, by specifying a url to it in CSS:

```
div {
    cursor: url(smiley.gif), url(myBall.cur), auto;
}
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Comment: Uhg... w3schools. Have a different reference? +1 nevertheless.

Comment: Hey so does this mean whenever my mouse is inside this particular DIV, the cursor will be different? Also, I don't have .cur files, I just have a .png image --- EDIT: is the whole idea to just edit the CSS of the containing view (div, body, etc)?

Comment: As I understand it, you should be able to to use your png too. Just make sure the is valid. Yup, that is the idea (so you could do it for the `body` tag).

Comment: never got it... why is w3schools considered to be a bad reference?

Answer (score 6):

The Jquery way to set a custom cursor (or default cursor as a fallback):

```
$('selector').css({'cursor': 'url(/cursors/customMoveCursor.cur), default'});
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't usually link external articles, but this one covers your needs. I've copied the relevant stuff here for persistence.

```
#dragMe {
    cursor: url('../cursors/customMoveCursor.cur'),     /* Modern browsers    */
            url('cursors/customMoveCursor.cur'),        /* Internet Explorer  */
            move;                                       /* Older browsers     */
}
```

Credit: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/12/21/cross-browser-css-cursor-images-in-depth/

Don't forget to consider accessibility when making your custom cursors! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a way you can change a file to a .cur file: https://convertio.co/png-cur/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35218044)