# How can I make the cursor a component using React?

Tags: reactjs

I have been given the task of changing the cursor to a FontAwsome icon. After doing some research I know that you can pass a `.png` file to the cursor style like this:

```js
<Component
 style={{ cursor: 'url(images/special.png),auto' }}
/>
```

But what I would like to do is something like this (in pseudo code):

```js
<Component
 style={{ cursor: <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDown} size="md" /> }}
/>
```

Is there a way to do this or is a viable workaround to get the svg of the icon from FontAwesome and convert is to a .png and store that file as a graphic asset?

Comment: use CSS for that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866471/javascript-how-to-change-mouse-cursor-to-an-image

Comment: Thanks - as my question says, I don't want to make the cursor an image, I want to make the cursor a React component.

Comment: have a look at this https://medium.com/@benzbraunstein/how-to-make-custom-css-cursors-using-react-fd1a5cca9400