# Possible to replace cursor with my own custom image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to replace the cursor icon apart from these:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_cursor

with my custom image that I designed in Photoshop? I know this is possible because I have seen some websites with cursor having custom image. Question is: How do I do it and whether it is standard approach? Can I be sure that it works across all browsers?

Comment: I think your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336925/custom-cursor-image-css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just do...

```
cursor: url(path/to/image.png);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FutcP/).

Comment: Cool! Didn't know the answer is so simple :). This isn't mentioned anywhere on w3schools.

Comment: Why did you change to image.cur? Can I not specify any png image or so?

Comment: @Jack I had a feeling maybe only `cur` would work (maybe older IE only supported it). But I tested it and `jpg` worked so I don't see any reason why a `png` wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `cursor: url(image.png);`

Look paragraph `'Property Values'`: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's. when i have finished your cursor image, just upload it on a host website (there are many on the web) then use the following css property to use it. Supposing you want to use it on images, just do :

```
img  {
   cursor: url(path to your hosted cursor image) ;
}
```