# Can i set the my own image in cursor using css or jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change the cursor with my own image when it's hover on my specific divison

i have try below as per describe in [Possible to replace cursor with my own custom image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771472/possible-to-replace-cursor-with-my-own-custom-image) this link

```
 demo:hover
 {
     cursor:url("img/point.png");
 }
```

but this is not working properly it's change cursor but not with my image

Comment: So what is it replaced with ?

Comment: possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336925/custom-cursor-image-css

Comment: Works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/DL4Yf/