# zoom in cursor not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add zoom in cursor to table but somehow not working.

```
<div style="height: 280px;overflow: auto" >
<table class="gridHover  ">

    <tbody  style = "cursor: zoom-in" >
        <tr  >
            <td>FFF</td>
            <td>FFF</td>
            <td>FFF</td>
            <td>FFF</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td>FFF</td>
            <td>FFF</td>
            <td>FFF</td>
            <td>FFF</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td>FFF</td>
            <td>FFF</td>
            <td>FFF</td>
            <td>FFF</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I think its because of that gridHover class. Can someone tell how to use zoom in cursor. I want to make it work on IE, chrome and FF.
Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vc79nLkm/7/)

Comment: Have you tried adding -webkit-zoom-in and -moz-zoom-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fixed [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vc79nLkm/9)

This is the new code:

```
<div style="height: 280px;overflow: auto">
<table class="gridHover">

    <tbody style="cursor: -webkit-zoom-in; cursor: -moz-zoom-in;">
        <tr>
            <td>FFF</td>
            <td>FFF</td>
            <td>FFF</td>
            <td>FFF</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td>FFF</td>
            <td>FFF</td>
            <td>FFF</td>
            <td>FFF</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>FFF</td>
            <td>FFF</td>
            <td>FFF</td>
            <td>FFF</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Happy that is because it is not supported by IE. Check my answer

Comment: and i want a Ferrari, but that is also not going to happen anytime soon.

Comment: @Happy IE doesn't support it. You need to wait till it supports most of css3.

Comment: @DoXicK i dont expect Ferrari from you. There should be some other alternative to it as well which you could have mentioned. Anyway thanks for your answers

Comment: @Happy i just updated my answer with an alternative. It's just not a very good alternative but it's an answer to your problem.

Comment: @DoXicK i think i had tried this and was not working in IE. Anyway at the moment very few people using IE and hence i will tell them not to use IE. IE is hopeless browser. I suffer lot of performance problem due to it.

Answer (score 4):

The zoom-in cursor is still browser specific for mozilla and webkit:

```
cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
cursor: -moz-zoom-in;
```

might try the same for IE though, but these are the ones i know of

---

As can be read at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor#Browser_compatibility) the browser support for IE is lacking.

- Mozilla  and Webkit are prefixed
- Opera works without a prefix

Also, here is an alternative way to try to fix it: [image cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336925/custom-cursor-image-css) (it's the exact same problem btw)

Comment: For IE it's [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

Comment: @Vucko thanks for the reference :-) i'm adding it to the answer!

Comment: I have upvoted you but have to accept Templar's answer as he answered first. Sorry if it sounded rude.

Comment: not rude, just not very usefull for people searching for this same question. i don't mind about the 5 points i'm missing out on, can't buy a ferrari from these points anyway ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but I think its broken in chrome.

test it on:

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=zoom-in)

it also doesn't work...

Comment: fyi: w3school is one of the WORST sites to use as a reference (As you just found out ;-) )

Comment: it's about the cursor property, and the example just uses the standard cursor property, without the browser specific ones.