# Make the cursor a self-drawn image

Tags: cursor, processing.js

I have a paint application program I have programmed from scratch in `processing.js` and incorporated it into my markdown code on my GitHub page.

This means I would prefer to not use CSS (I would have to link to a JavaScript program that creates a link element to the CSS file and appends it to the head).

In the paint program, there is an eraser that just paints the background, but I want it to look more like they are using an eraser by changing the cursor to the eraser when they have the eraser selected. How could I implement this?

### Research - What I have already Tried

At [Custom Cursor Image CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336925/custom-cursor-image-css), it needs to be an image, but I want a function that I call inside the file so I can always update it. I also would like to use JavaScript, not CSS.

I have read up on https://processing.org/tutorials/interactivity/ but there is nothing in there about custom cursors, just named ones and images.

#### Update

I am using the createGraphics function but I can't get it to work as a cursor: http://processingjs.org/reference/createGraphics_/

### Links

I host this program in these places

- https://knowledgeablekangaroo.github.io/paint-a-picture-backup/
- https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/paint-a-picture-v219/4631918938554368
- https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/paint-a-picture/5366591758565376

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to set the cursor to `none` which will hide the cursor, and then draw the cursor however you want inside your Processing sketch. Here's a very basic example:

```
void draw(){
  background(32);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
}
```

This will show your cursor as an ellipse.

Another approach might be to use a [data URI](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris). You'd have to convert your drawing into a 64-bit endoded image, and then pass that into the CSS. I haven't actually tested this.

Comment: For your first example, I can't do it because the background is outside the draw function because my paint program really is just them smearing a shape's fill. That's why it has to be a cursor

Comment: @Marvin Draw your painting to a buffer, the `createGraphics()` function is your friend. Then draw the buffer to the screen, and finally draw your cursor over top of it.

Comment: I used `var pg = createGraphics(80, 80, P3D);
   pg.beginDraw();

  pg.background(102);

  pg.stroke(255);

  pg.line(40, 40, mouseX, mouseY);

  pg.endDraw();` and then cursor(pg) but then 'pg' does not show up. image(pg, 10, 10) works

Comment: Why are you using `mouseX` and `mouseY` when you draw to `pg`? Just draw a static image to `pg`, and then draw `pg` where you want your cursor to show up.

Comment: If I do line(40, 40, 20, 20); everything goes blank and the canvas isn't drawn. The pg should _be_ the cursor'

Comment: Never mind, I had an error, but either way, 'pg' is not showing up

Comment: Start with my example. Get a circle working for the cursor. Then get it working with a `PGraphics`. If you still can't get it working, please post an updated [mcve] in a new question, and we'll go from there. Good luck.