# Make PGraphic Object the cursor

Tags: cursor, processing.js, pgraphics

This is a follow-up of my question: [Make the cursor a self-drawn image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52322112/make-the-cursor-a-self-drawn-image).

I have a paint a picture application. The latest working version can be found here: https://knowledgeablekangaroo.github.io/paint-a-picture-backup/, where the code can be found in *F12 > Sources > paint-a-picture.js*.

The user can choose a color, set the background, set the thickness, shape, and opacity. There is also an eraser functionality. I want there to be a better user experience, **so I am trying to draw the eraser below as the cursor**. If the cursor doesn't work, I need something that doesn't smear.

The way I have programmed it, anywhere inside the "paint area" (above control center and below pallete) will smear - the `background()` is outside the draw.

```
var pg = createGraphics(pgDimensions.w, pgDimensions.h, JAVA2D);
pg.beginDraw();
pg.fill(255, 200, 255);
pg.strokeWeight(2);
pg.rect(0, 0, pgDimensions.w, pgDimensions.h);
pg.fill(0);
pg.textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
pg.text("ERASER", pgDimensions.w / 2, pgDimensions.h / 2);
pg.endDraw();
```

I used the `createGraphics()` function to create a PGraphics Object. The point is to show the eraser while This shows the eraser I have drawn in the pGraphic above.

In the `drawBrush()` function, I make this an image. [image: Eraser]

```
    var drawBrush = function() {
    fill(currentColor);
    noStroke();
    shapes.forEach(function (element, index) {
        if (pshape == index) {
          element.brush();
        }
    });
    if (C === bgColor) {
        image(pg, mouseX - pgDimensions.w / 2, mouseY - pgDimensions.h / 2);
    }
};
```

### Research

[This best describes my problem](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/20395/how-to-make-a-brush-object-that-follows-the-mouse-with-size-and-color-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have a graphics stored in your `pg` variable, you can draw that using the `image()` function:

`image(pg, mouseX, mouseY);`

Here's a small example that demonstrates what I'm talking about:

```
var pg;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);

  pg = createGraphics(100, 100);
  pg.ellipse(50, 50, 100, 100);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  image(pg, mouseX, mouseY);
}
```

Comment: I have edited my post. I had already had this code, but it smears like in the picture

Comment: @Marvin You need to call `background()` to clear out the old frames.

Comment: It still needs to actually erase. Doing that would eraser everything already in the background instead of actually erasing

Comment: @Marvin You need to [split this up into smaller steps](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program). One step is drawing the eraser. Another step is actually erasing. You might do that by drawing a white rectangle underneath the eraser.

Comment: thanks for all the help. I have figured it out. The solution was to make the actual _erasing_ the pgraphic object, and the actual eraser/marker that I am incorporating right now to be a regular command. I got this from the link under the research heading in my question (edited it again), and in the PGgraphic solution in one of the bottom comments in the forum