# Change cursor into custom text

Tags: css, html

How to change the mouse cursor into text?

For example into "Next" or "Previous" depending on the mouse position.

Comment: This "text" is just an image that replaces cursor. It's not some text that you can just change. And you should try something yourself. Learn stuff, try to make something, then ask for help. Right know you are asking for someone to do work for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Cursor Image CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336925/custom-cursor-image-css)

Comment: Ok , so it with the .cur custom , i need a png for the text and just change the cursor into it .

Comment: Yes, same thing from question above.

Answer (score 5):

To achieve expected result, use below mousemove event option
1.Create custom cursor div
2.Create mousemove event
3. Make custom cursor div follow cursor

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NegKGK

```js
function custom(event){
  var el = document.getElementById("hov");
 el.style.top = event.clientY + "px";
 el.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
  }

document.getElementById("main").addEventListener('mousemove', custom);
```

```css
div:hover > #hov{
  display : block;

}

#hov{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

#main{
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  background: green;
    cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">text<div id="hov">hover</div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it by setting image url to your elements cursor property.

Something like this,

```
.custom {
  cursor: url(images/my-cursor.png);
}
```

Note: The text which you are looking on cursor is the image containing the text.

Comment: So i just need to convert a text into png and do that . alright. thanks

Comment: If you have a multilingual website, this will be problematic.